# Svn command is not recognised as internal or external command in jenkins job

Tags: svn, jenkins

I created a job and exectuing the python script . The script is working fine in command prompt . When i intergrated in jenkins job . It says svn is not recognized as external or internal command . 
I checked in environmental path . The path for svn is added also .

Comment: Is the Subversion command inside your Python script? What does that Subversion command do? If that Subversion command is internal to your Python script, is it using the Subversion Python module that uses the Subversion C API, or is it doing an external call to the `svn` command itself?

Comment: just try disconnecting your host on which Jenkins run and reconnect it back and check if that solves this issue , i have faced similar issue and above process resolved my issue.

Comment: "I checked in environmental path" <- for which account? Try from the Jenkins server as `su - jenkins` and then run your script.

Answer (score 0):

David 
I am using direct svn command itself in python script  p = subprocess.Popen('svn update %s '%(Path_2),shell=True ) . To do svn update . Through command prompt the svn update and checkout is working fine . But in jenkins it says error . Svn is recognized as command